# WIX doesn't delete file on uninstall

Tags: file, wix, uninstallation, delete-file

I'm making an installer with WIX 3.5 for my screensaver. Im using the XNA installer template [available here](http://xnainstaller.codeplex.com/)
Everything works, except when I uninstall the program, the .SCR file placed in WINDOWS/System32 is not deleted.
Ive tried using the  element to delete it, and I've set Permanent="no" on the component, but that does not fix it.

```
<Directory Id="WindowsFolder" Name="Windows">
        <Directory Id="WindowsSystem32" Name="System32">
            <Component Id="FileComponent" Guid="cf1cce2d-6812-4443-ba97-299503836b43" Permanent="no">
                <RemoveFile Id="rssFax" Name="ssFax.scr" On="both" />
                <File Id="ssFax" DiskId="1" Vital="yes" Source="../../Content/ssFax.scr" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A windows installer log file would go a long way in explaining why MSI is choosing not to remove this file.  Until then, here's a smiliar thread to read:

[Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project not deleting files out of System Folder when uninstalling](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/cc36436e-dfc2-49c3-a61f-18d2aab24611)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I uploaded my uninstall log "http://hmfpa.org/file/MSI1cc17.LOG" Do you think this line "The file represented by File table key 'ssFax' has no eligible binary patches" has to do with the problem?

Comment: The interesting part to me was that the component had a Request of Absent but an Action of Null.   Did you do the logging with /l*v for verbose logging?  It seemed kind of light on details.

Comment: I reuploaded the log with /l*v at http://hmfpa.org/file/installer.log If this problem continues, can I use a custom action?

Comment: It turned out that I had gotten the permanant flag set for the file on one of the debug builds. I tried it on another computer, and everything worked perfectly